# CRUD application testing with mocha chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am new to JavaScript/JavaScript testing and was doing a course on mocha test framework with chai. how to test simple  CRUD  application? I want to write unit tests for all of them. I tried looking  at  questions here, but all of them were very advanced and i did not understand them. can you please help me it would be appreciated. the question was

```
module.exports = {
  
  addDetails: function() {
    let data =[]
    data.push("one");
    return data
  },

  deleteDetails: function() {
    let data =["one" , "two"]
    data.splice(0 , 1)
    return data
  },

  editDetails: function() {
    let data =["one"]
    data.splice(0 , 1 , "three")
    return data
  },

  updateDetails: function() {
    let data = ["one" , "three"]
    data.splice(1 , 0 , "two")
    return data
  },

  detailsPop: function() {
    let numb = ["one" , "two"]
    numb.pop()
    return numb
  },

  concatData: function() {
    let data1 = ["one"]
    let data2 = ["two"]
    let result = data1.concat(data2)
    return result
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code crud.js is the file of the above code as you have mentioned.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var crud = require('../crud');

describe('Crud application', function() {

   it('addDetails()', function () {
     assert.deepStrictEqual(crud.addDetails(), ['one']);
   });

   it('deleteDetails()', function () {
     assert.equal(crud.deleteDetails(), 'two');
   });

   it('editDetails()', function () {
     assert.deepStrictEqual(crud.editDetails(), [ 'one', 0, 1, 'three' ]);
   });

  it('updateDetails()', function () {
    assert.deepStrictEqual(crud.updateDetails(), [ 'one', 'three', 1, 0, 'two' ]);  
 });

it('detailsPop()', function () {
    assert.deepStrictEqual(crud.detailsPop(), ['one', 'two', 'one']);
});

  it('concatData()', function () {
     assert.deepStrictEqual(crud.concatData(), ["one", "two"]);
  });
});
```